# Finding first string in second string without pointers in C

Tags: c, string, pointers

I'm a newbie C language student.
My teacher said that we must write a project to:
Find second string in first string with no any pointer(*). Till now I've learned Loops, Conditions, Functions and Arrays and they are my lone options.
This project must get strings from user in two levels. Check them and print result.

For now I've written something bullshit:

```
int main()
{

        char source[MAX_STR_LEN];
        char target[MAX_STR_LEN];
        int len = 50;
        int a;
        scanf("%s", &source);
        scanf("%s", &target);

        for (int i = 0; i <= len; i++)
        {

            if (strncasecmp(source[i], target[i], strlen(target)) == 0)
            {
                int a = 1;
                if (a == 1)
                {
                    printf("%s is inner of %s", target, source);
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("%s is NOT inner of %s", target, source);
                }
            }
        }


      return 0;
}
```

but my project prints nothing and closes automatically when I enter two strings. I'm sure my code is not true is there any simple way to do it?
Thanks

Comment: One major problem is that `source[i]` (as well as `target[i]`) is a *single character*, and the `strncasecmp` function compares *strings*.

Comment: Even this `scanf("%s", &source);` is pointer.

Comment: To begin with, `scanf("%s", &source);` -> `scanf("%s", source);`.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple approach is simply to check the source string character by character to see if the target string is found. In other words:

- check if the target string is present starting at source[0].
- if not: check if the target string is present starting at source[1].
- if not: check if the target string is present starting at source[2].
- and so on until you reach the end of the source string.

This can be done using two for-loops where the outer loop iterates all characters in the source string and the inner loop iterates the target string while comparing characters in the two strings.

You can visualize it like:

```
source: Hello World
target: lo

Hello World
lo           // No match: He != lo

Hello World
 lo          // No match: el != lo

Hello World
  lo         // No match: ll != lo

Hello World
   lo        // Match: lo != lo
```

A simple implementation could look like:

```
int main()
{

    char source[MAX_STR_LEN] = "Hello World";
    char target[MAX_STR_LEN] = "lo";

    int source_index = 0;
    int match = 0;
    while (source[source_index] != '\0')
    {
        int target_index = 0;
        while (target[target_index] != '\0' &&
               source[source_index + target_index] != '\0' && 
               source[source_index + target_index] == target[target_index])
        {
            ++target_index;
            if (target[target_index] == '\0')
            {
                match = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (match) break;
        ++ source_index;
    }
    if (match)
    {
        printf("found\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("not found\n");
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Can you write it with a CheckString function for me please?

Comment: @MeT Well, if the code is changed to use a function that receives to strings and does the search then there will be pointers involved as strings are passed as char pointers....

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to improve the logic of how to search the substring in original string or if it is allowed by your teacher you can leave C language to search for it.

strstr doing that job.

Below is my code, i have add comment at your code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>

#define MAX_STR_LEN 50

int main(void)
{

     char source[MAX_STR_LEN];
     char target[MAX_STR_LEN];
    //int len = 50;
    //int a;
    scanf(" %s", source);   //char array name is used like pointer to the first element of array
    scanf(" %s", target);

    char* ret = NULL;

    ret = strstr(source, target);

    if(ret == NULL)
        printf("%s is NOT inner of %s", target, source);
    else
        printf("%s is inner of %s", target, source);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: OP asked for a solution without (use of) pointers. As `strstr` returns a pointer I'm not sure this answers the question.

Comment: Right! thanks a lot can u write it as a function for me please?

Comment: Ops! this answer used * that i cannot use it.

Answer (score -1):

Brother you assign a value of`int a = 1;`and right after you check`if(a == 1)`which makes no sence because`else{printf("%s is NOT inner of %s", target, source);}`this above part of code will never use in this scenario this is the solution https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-two-strings-find-first-string-subsequence-second/be carefull :)

Comment: Page not found?

Comment: Hi and welcome..answers on SO needs to be structured and contain sufficient information not only for the OP but also for the future visitors.Let it aside..the link you've provided is broken.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-two-strings-find-first-string-subsequence-second/ sory for the broken link you can google as Given two strings, find if first string is a subsequence of second. İf is not the biggest case for you to do without a pointer ,if its a simpel hw you might not consider it big BC pointers in data structure and algorithms are evetything.